# how to setup react-i18n with hooks, getting TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, react-i18next

Here's the code:

***translations.ts***

```
function useTranslate () {
  const namespace = 'translation';
  return {
    languages: languages,
    transform: (_languages_) => {
      const _languages = {};

      console.log(_languages_)
      _languages_['data'].forEach(language => {
        languages.forEach(i => {
          if (!_languages[i.code]) { _languages[i.code] = { [namespace]: {} }; }
          _languages[i.code][namespace][language['en']] = language[i.code];
        });
      });

      return _languages;
    },
    getAll: () => Axios.get('/translations'),
    initialize: (resources) => {
      i18next
        .use(initReactI18next)
        .use(LanguageDetector)
        .init({
          fallbackLng: ['en'],
          lng: localStorage.getItem('i18nextLng') || 'en',
          detection: {
            order: ['querystring', 'cookie', 'localStorage', 'sessionStorage', 'navigator', 'htmlTag', 'path', 'subdomain'],

            lookupCookie: 'i18next',
            lookupLocalStorage: 'i18nextLng',
            lookupSessionStorage: 'i18nextLng',
            lookupFromPathIndex: 0,
            lookupFromSubdomainIndex: 0,

            caches: ['localStorage'],
            htmlTag: document.documentElement,
          },
          supportedLngs: languages.map(a => a.code),
          resources,
          debug: true,
          ns: [namespace],
          defaultNS: namespace
      });
    }
  };
}

export default useTranslate;
```

***index.tsx***

```
      const { t } = useTranslation();

  const { getAll } = useUser();
  const { getAllRooms } = useRoom();

  const [userData, setUserData] = useState({});
  const [roomData, setRoomData] = useState({});
    useEffect(() => {
        const source = axios.CancelToken.source();
        let ignore = true;
        (async function setUser() {
          let userResponse = await getAll();
          let roomResponse = await get();
    
          if (ignore) {
            setUserData(userResponse['data']);
            setRoomData(roomResponse['data']);
          }
        })()
        return () => {
          ignore = false;
          source.cancel();
        };
      }, []);
```

***_app.tsx***

```
import i18next from 'i18next';
import useTranslate from '@services/core/hooks/translations';

  const { languages } = useTranslate();
```

When I try to reload the page, I'm getting the error TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined on the react hooks. also it has an error Warning: React has detected a change in the order of Hooks called by Home. also i18next: init: i18next is already initialized. You should call init just once!

[image]

there's another error which is the Error: Rendered more hooks than during the previous render.

***pages/index.tsx***

```
const { t } = useTranslation();
const [userData, setUserData] = useState({});
useEffect(() => {
    const source = axios.CancelToken.source();
    let ignore = true;
    (async function setData() {
      let userResponse = await getAll();
    
      if (ignore) {
        setUserData(userResponse['data']);
     }
    })()
    return () => {
      ignore = false;
      source.cancel();
    };

},[]);
```

Comment: There's no `.length` anywhere in the posted code, so the error message is pointing elsewhere. Where exactly?

Comment: @ChrisG when I added the useffect it cause an error, but when I try to remove there's no error.

Comment: The error message you're getting comes with a file and line number. We need to see the code that is causing the error. My guess is that something that is expected to be an array starts out as `undefined` instead of `[]`.

Comment: @ChrisG - ```Error: Rendered more hooks than during the previous render.```

Comment: That error occurs when (as the message suggests) you return an inconsistent number of hooks in different renders. In the image you have it says `pages/index.tsx (25:30)` What is on that line of code?

Comment: _The error message you're getting comes with a file and line number. We need to see the code that is causing the error._

Comment: @ChrisG@DBS added the error on the ```pages/index.tsx```